# Dynamic sitemap from database doesn't display the nodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider, sitemapprovider

I have implemented this https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider

**Edit**: this is my class

```
public class MyDynamicNodeProvider
: DynamicNodeProviderBase
{

    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)

    { 
        webdata storeDB = new webdata();

        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();


        foreach (var article in storeDB.SiteContents) 
        {


            DynamicNode enode = new DynamicNode();
            enode.Title = article.ArticleTitle;
            enode.ParentKey = "ArticleID"; 
            enode.Url = "ArticleDetails/" + article.ArticleID + "/" + article.ArticleAlias;
            //Specify Controller and Action name
            enode.Controller = "SiteContents";
            enode.Action = "ArticleDetails";
            enode.RouteValues.Add("id", article.ArticleID);
            returnValue.Add(enode);

            yield return enode;
        }


    }
}
```

**Edit**:this is my sitemap file

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="About Us" controller="Menu" action="AboutUs">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Profile" controller="Menu"   action="Profile"/>
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="History" controller="Menu" action="History"/>
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Article" controller="SiteContents"  action="ArticleDetails" key="ArticleID"> 
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details"  dynamicNodeProvider="Myproject.Models.MyDynamicNodeProvider, Myproject"  />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

**Edit**: The second controller which I have (SiteContentsController )

```
  public ActionResult ArticleDetails(int? id, string slug)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SiteContents siteContents = db.SiteContents.Find(id);
        if (siteContents == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slug))
        {

            var alias = db.SiteContents.First(p => p.ArticleID == id).ArticleAlias;


            return RedirectToAction("ArticleDetails", new { id = id, slug = alias });
        }

        return View(siteContents);
      }
```

The url I would like to have (which work but it doesn't bring the sitemap
is `http://localhost:xxxx/ArticleDetails/1/Quality_Policy`

and I call the sitemap at my layoutpage

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

**Edit**: My route.config

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Articles", url: "ArticleDetails/{id}/{slug}", defaults: new { controller = "SiteContents", action = "ArticleDetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});


    }
```

I also have some static nodes which work ok. The problem is that with in dynamic pages returns nothing and I dont get any error message
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is that you have not accounted for all of the route values, namely you have a route value named `slug` which you need to configure the node to match.

If you want the node to match regardless of the value for `slug` (even if it is blank), you should use `PreservedRouteParameters` to match it. Otherwise, you should add it to `RouteValues` and the node will only match the *one* value you configure for it (you can add additional nodes to match other values if needed). I am showing the `PreservedRouteParameters` approach here.

In addition, you have effectively disabled MVC support by configuring the `Url` property on your dynamic node. This property is useful if you need to use a non-MVC page or an external URL, but is not recommended for MVC.

`MvcSiteMapProvider` depends directly on the MVC routing configuration. This is where you configure your URLs to look how you want them to look. For your expected URL (`http://localhost:xxxx/ArticleDetails/1/Quality_Policy`) to work, you need a corresponding route to match this pattern, as below.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Route to match the URL /ArticleDetails/1/Quality_Policy
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ArticleDetails",
            url: "ArticleDetails/{id}/{slug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SiteContents", action = "ArticleDetails", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

One other issue you have is the node you are attaching the dynamic nodes to. The way you have your node configured currently goes to the `ArticleDetails` action. I can't tell what you are trying to do here. Normally, you would show a list (index) of all of the article pages and then when the user clicks an article, you would show it. Here is an example.

```
// NOTE: Normally, you would put all of your Article stuff
// into an ArticleController
public class SiteContentsController
{
    // NOTE: Normally, this would be named ArticleController.Index()
    public ActionResult ArticleIndex()
    {
        // NOTE: You may want to use a view model here
        // rather than using the SiteContents directly.
        var siteContents = db.SiteContents.ToList();
        return View(siteContents);
    }

    // NOTE: Normally, this would be named ArticleController.Details()
    public ActionResult ArticleDetails(int? id, string slug)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SiteContents siteContents = db.SiteContents.Find(id);
        if (siteContents == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slug))
        {

            var alias = db.SiteContents.First(p => p.ArticleID == id).ArticleAlias;


            return RedirectToAction("ArticleDetails", new { id = id, slug = alias });
        }

        return View(siteContents);
    }
}
```

And your `Mvc.sitemap` file would look more like this (with articles being below the home page). I believe this is your main issue - you must only have one root node in your XML file (usually, it is the home page of the site).

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About Us" controller="Menu" action="AboutUs">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Profile" controller="Menu"   action="Profile">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Quality Policy" controller="Menu" action="Policy"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="History" controller="Menu" action="History"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Articles" controller="SiteContents"  action="ArticleIndex" key="Articles"> 
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" dynamicNodeProvider="Myproject.Models.MyDynamicNodeProvider, Myproject"  />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Finally, we have the corrected `DynamicNodeProvider`.

```
public class MyDynamicNodeProvider
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    { 
        webdata storeDB = new webdata();

        foreach (var article in storeDB.SiteContents) 
        {
            DynamicNode enode = new DynamicNode();
            enode.Title = article.ArticleTitle;
            enode.ParentKey = "Articles";

            // Don't use the Url property unless you have a 
            // non-MVC page/external URL
            //enode.Url = "ArticleDetails/" + article.ArticleID + "/" + article.ArticleAlias;

            // Specify Controller, Action name, and id.
            // These values all must match the request in order 
            // for the node to be considered the "current" node
            enode.Controller = "SiteContents";
            enode.Action = "ArticleDetails";
            enode.RouteValues.Add("id", article.ArticleID);

            // Match the slug (we don't really care what its value is here)
            enode.PreservedRouteParameters.Add("slug");

            yield return enode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply. Now it gives the error:  Not all configured nodes could be paired with a parent node. Check your parent keys to ensure that a node with a corresponding key exists in the SiteMap.
Orphaned Nodes:
ParentKey: 'ArticleUrl' | Controller: 'SiteContents' | Action: 'ArticleDetails' | Area: '' | URL: '/ArticleDetails/1' | Key: '0ea47139-9577-43ae-bdc4-b304293e788d' | Source: 'Myproject.Models.MyDynamicNodeProvider, Myproject'

Comment: In the example you posted, you have the key of the parent node set to `key="ArticleUrl"`. You have apparently changed it to something else or removed it. You need to have the same value in the `key` attribute of the parent node as the `ParentKey` property of the `DynamicNode`.

Comment: I change it to ArticleUrl but again it doesn't show nothing again. No errors. Static nodes works ok. I have one table only.
My sitemap file:

`<mvcSiteMapNode title="Article" controller="SiteContents" action="ArticleDetails" key="ArticleUrl"> 
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details"  dynamicNodeProvider="Myproject.Models.ElkeDynamicNodeProvider, Myproject"/`
thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and put 1) your current `Mvc.sitemap` contents, 2) The controller(s) and action(s) you are trying to match, and 3) your routing configuration. You are clearly not configuring one of these correctly, but since you haven't posted them I cannot tell which. It would also help if you post the URL you are attempting to go to when the breadcrumbs disappear.

Comment: Also post what you have currently in your dynamic node provider.

Comment: I have set the key at the ArticleID but whatever I try lets say ArticleUrl field or something else it doesn't bring nothing as sitemap

Comment: I also post my Route.config. Thanks a  lot

Comment: I made all the changes you suggest. Still nothing no errors no breadcrumbs. :) My site and the sitemap works ok for all the static pages I have. The problem appears only to dynamic pages which I get them from the database. If I remove the ` <mvcSiteMapNode title="ArticleTitle" controller="SiteContents" action="ArticleDetails" key="Articles">`  I get the error: Not all configured nodes could be paired with a parent node. Check your parent keys to ensure that a node with a corresponding key exists in the SiteMap.

Comment: .....Orphaned Nodes: ParentKey: 'Articles' | Controller: 'SiteContents' | Action: 'ArticleDetails' | Area: '' | URL: '/ArticleDetails/Home/About' | Key: '84128a15-1bd9-4e03-944c-ebc37f425815' | Source: 'MyprojectName.Models.ElkeDynamicNodeProvider, MyprojectName'

Comment: I dont have the same controller for my Home page and and Articles details  action. Thank you again

Comment: It finally worked. I just have to change the
 enode.RouteValues.Add("id", article.ArticleUrl); to
 enode.RouteValues.Add("id", article.ArticleID); thanks a lot again.

Comment: last but not least...I promise last question. In the breadcrumbs it returns

Home> Profile> ArticleTitle > Quality Policy. 

I dont need the ArticleTitle to appear. It has to be
Home> Profile> Quality Policy.

Comment: If you just have one policy for the whole site, add a nested node below the `Profile` node (note I have changed my answer to reflect this). If you have one policy per article, then you can add an extra dynamic node (specifying the key-parent key mapping correctly) and use the [SiteMapTitleAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Action-Filter-Attributes#sitemaptitle) to update the title of the parent node dynamically when you navigate to the policy page.

Comment: I have one Policy article for whole site and I call Policy content from my database. I have to store all articles to database. I will give a try and I let you know how it goes. thank you!

Comment: hello again. What if I need to change the parent Key. I mean that I have some more parents menu. The one I have is Home>Profile>Quality Policy and the other Home>eServices> eService 1. It always brings the  Home>Profile> (and the according article title). thank you.

Comment: I post a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717293/change-parent-key-dynamically-idynamicnodeprovider-mvc. It will be great if you can help. Thank you